# Laying problem in designing axis points in static design?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, statics

[image]

First of all, there is a simple pattern plan on the halter. Here, we design an axis point passing through the midpoints of the columns and use it in the static calculation program. However, when we do this, we make the slab smaller when we draw it at the axis points. When we want to draw the floor wide, I think it will calculate as console floor and beam. Because it will stay on the left or right of the axis point. I don't think that the program will calculate the dimensions of the column and understand that the part of the slab that goes through is not the console.

- In the structure I designed, the column dimensions are very thick $(160cm)$$x$$(160cm)$. I am having the program calculate the $80 cm$ floor slab incompletely on 4 surfaces. So how should I resolve this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two reasonable options.

1. Make a fully 3d model, this discrepancy will dissapear when you stop considering the columns as line elements.
2. Calculate the loss of load due to the "missing" 80 cm at the boundaries and compare them to the reactions already present on the columns. In the vast majority of real world cases the loss will be of the order of 1% or less, which will be irrelevant for the structure.